# Django why infinite pagination not working and taking me to next page?

Tags: javascript, python, django

it's taking me to next page when I am clicking on load more button. I want my content will be load dynamically in same page or without go to next page. here is my code

#I am loading those js in my base.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{%  static 'theme/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'theme/js/infinite.min.js'%}"></script> 
 <script src="{% static 'theme/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'%}"></script>
```

here is my html page code where I want to implement infinite pagination

```
<div class="infinite-container">
{% for i in content %}
 #my others code....
{%endfor%}
</div>


{% if content.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ content.next_page_number }}">More</a>
{% endif %}

<script>
  var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[1]
  });
</script>
```

When I am clicking in more button it's taking me second page but I don't want to go second page. Why content not loading in same page? why it's taking me to next page? how to load content dynamically without go next page?